# Prolog term_expansion not working

Tags: prolog

I am trying to perform the following term_expansion with swipl:

```
a(asda).
a(astronaut).

term_expansion(a(X),b(X)).
```

But it does not work, i.e. there is no b/1 consulted. I have tried a few variations:

```
term_expansion(a(X),[b(X)]).
user:term_expansion(a(X),b(X)).
user:term_expansion(a(X),[b(X)]).
user:term_expansion(user:a(X),[user:b(X)]).
```

None of which works.  What is the problem?

Comment: Most likely you need to add the definition of `term_expansion/2` **before** you are using it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by @mat, you need to define the `term_expansion/2` predicate **before** the clauses you want to expand are loaded. Also, the `term_expansion/2` predicate is a *multifile* and *dynamic* predicate defined for the `user` pseudo-module. Thus, you should write:

```
:- multifile user:term_expansion/2.
:- dynamic user:term_expansion/2.

user:term_expansion(a(X), b(X)).
```

This will ensure that your expansion code will work if you move it into a module.

If portability to other Prolog systems with a term-expansion mechanism (which, btw, is far from standard), than consider moving the term-expansion code to its own file, loaded before the source files you want to expand.